# Should Json.Net Schema validation detect duplicate properties

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I am working on exploring some json validation patterns and ran into something unexpected in Json.Net Schema (v3.0.3).

In short if I generate my schema from a .net type, then feed in a data string that includes one of the properties twice, I would expect the validator to throw an exception.  However it accepts the multiple values in a last in wins manner.  Is there a way to get it to reject the data that has multiple values?

Example, this is my type:

```
class TestObject {
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Then this is the code of the test I put together using that type (note that the data contains the name property twice):

```
var jsonString="{'Id': 111, 'Name': 'SomeValue', 'Flag': true, 'Name':'IgnoredValue'}";
var reader=new JSchemaValidatingReader(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonString))) {
    Schema=new JSchemaGenerator() { DefaultRequired=Required.Default }.Generate(typeof(TestObject))
};

// Act
try {
    var result=JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<TestObject>(reader);
    Assert.Fail("Exception expected.");
}
```

Note: This use pattern passes all of the other test cases we are concerned with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Schema doesn't have any validation to detect duplicate properties in a JSON object.

The JSON spec doesn't make any mention of duplicate properties so they are valid but not recommended.